# Custom Control Emits <td> Markup. Surrounding <tr runat=server> Causes Compile Error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a custom control, `InputField`, which encapsulates a `Label` and a `TextBox`. There's more to the control than that, but elaborating would just add noise to this question. It has a `Layout` property which conditionally emits `<td>` ... `</td>` markup so I can avoid clutter in my `.aspx` files. So, instead of

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ... /></td>
</tr>
```

I can just write

```
<table>
<tr>
    <cc:InputField Layout="TableCells" FieldLabel="Name:" ... />
</tr>
```

However, if I need to be able to access that `<tr>` in code behind, I get a compile error. The markup:

```
<table>
<tr runat="server" id="tr1">
    <cc:InputField Layout="TableCells" FieldLabel="Name:" ... />
</tr>
```

generates the error: `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'cc:InputField' is of type 'ASP.customcontrols_inputfield_ascx'.`

I understand *why* the error is being generated. What I'm looking for is a way to change my `InputField` control so this error doesn't happen. Since C# doesn't have multiple inheritance, and `InputField` is, and presumably must be a subclass of `System.Web.UI.UserControl`, I cannot change it to subclass `HtmlTableCell`.

I tried `<tr id="tr1">` then setting `display: none` but I get yelled at for writing kludgy code that doesn't adhere to our coding standards.

Is there a way for me to improve my `InputField` class so it can live inside a `<tr runat="server">` element? I am keenly aware that a correct answer may very well be "You're doing this completely wrong. STOP writing components like this! Here's why..."

Comment: Seems like a lot of headache to avoid writing a `td`.

Comment: Is it allowable in your situation to simply use CSS and JavaScript to hide/show the row?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev It encapsulates a lot of other behaviors including a few validators and other formatting options. To your point, I'm contemplating disabling the functionality that emits the <td>'s.

Comment: @BobKaufman Is cc:InputField a custom control that you're providing?  Or does it come from a 3rd-party library?

Comment: @BrianShamblen - that's what I'm doing now, however other team members are not liking it.

Comment: @matt - `cc:InputField` is my handiwork.

Comment: @BobKaufman seems like an easy way to likely fix your problem. Also from an outsider looking at `aspx` with seemingly invalid markup with the hope that the control handles it to make it valid... is... a tad confusing. Like it's handling all of its own logic and then oh by the way, let me add this `td` so it actually works right ;) I'll take the "cluttered" markup over somewhat-wonktastic, though magical, code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this `InputField` class is of your own design, if you want to add it to an `HtmlTableCellCollection` (tr), then you either need to make it inherit from `HtmlTableCell`, or you need to use as `<td><cc:InputField... /></td>`, and stop having your control output the `td`.  There really aren't any other options.

In point of fact, you probably shouldn't be outputting the `td` as part of your control output, as this prevents it from being used in a non-table context.

Comment: It emits the `<td>` elements conditionally, when `Layout` is set to `TableCells`. There are other settings, too, so it can be emitted as a TableRow, ListItem or without enclosing markup altogether. The answers and comments I'm receiving are confirming my suspicions that I am taking an incorrect approach to this problem.

Comment: @BobKaufman plus, removing all of the code that conditionally adds markup will clean up your code a lot... and then make your markup make more sense too. Then next guy doesn't have to worry about what custom property to use to create HTML... when he could just write out the HTML.